# Find specific div with RegEx and print content

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to pull some text from an external website using [this script](http://icant.co.uk/articles/crossdomain-ajax-with-jquery/using-yql.html).

It works perfectly, but it gets the entire page. I want to take only the content inside a specific div with the class 'content'. The entire page is put inside the variable 'data', and then this function is created to strip some tags:

```
function filterData(data){
  data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g,'');
  data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g,'');
  data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g,'');
  data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g,'');
  data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g,'');
  data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/,'');
  return data;
}
```

How would I go about finding the div with the class 'content' and only viewing the content inside that?

**UPDATE:** Sorry about using RegExes — can you help me to get the content without using RegEx? So, this is my HTML file:

```
<a href="http://www.eurest.dk/kantiner/228/all.asp?a=9" class="ajaxtrigger">erg</a>
<div id="target" style="width:200px;height:500px;"></div>
<div id="code" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var container = $('#target');
$('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
doAjax($(this).attr('href'));
return false;
});
function doAjax(url){
if(url.match('^http')){
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        var tree = string2dom(data.results[0]);
        container.html($("div.content", tree.doc));tree.destroy();
      } else {
        var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
        container.html(errormsg);
      }
    }
  );
} else {
  $('#target').load(url);
}
}
function filterData(data){

return tree;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse HTML? Especially in with JavaScript the browser this is entirely unnecessary, you can use the DOM.

Comment: Meanwhile, over on Planet Sane: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Yeah, okay, it seems like I shouldn't be using RegEx to do this. Thing is, my JavaScript skills are very limited, and the code I found used RegEx, so that's why I'm using them.

But I'll try using the DOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var matches = data.match(/<div class="content">([^<]*)<\/div>/);

if (matches) 
    return matches[1]; // div content
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
<div\b[^>]*class="content"[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this :

```
<div[^>]*?class='content'[^>]*?>(.*?)</div>
```

Captured reference /1 will have your content. Although you **shouldn't** be doing this with regexes :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. I would love to learn to do it without!

Comment: Check out some nice functions like : getelementbyid
Use it, then check the id attributes, e.g. class='content' and then just get the content of the element by another appropriate function. No need for regex at all :) DOM is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

```
    var divtxt = match(/<div[^>]*class="content"[^>]>.*<\/div>/);
```

but it may stop at the wrong .

you should use jquery or prototype to make it a dom-object and use selectors to find the right div.
using jquery you would do something like:

```
    var divtxt = $(data).find(".content").first().html();
```

remember to load the jquery library first.

Comment: Okay, but should I still load the script I included in the question?